# Can I /execute a command at players with a certain score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a project I'm working on, I want to be able to execute a setblock command at a player with a certain score.  I've tried doing

```
/execute @a[score_xp_min=100] -insert command here-
```

but all it says is that I've provided an improper UUID format. Is there any way to `/execute` commands at players with certain scores?

Answer (score 4):

The selector format is correct, but the problem is that the syntax of /execute is:

```
/execute <Target> <X> <Y> <Z> <Command>
```

To fix your problem simply add 3 tilde (~) after the @a selector:

```
/execute @a[score_xp_min=100] ~ ~ ~ <Command>
```

Comment: Tilda spelt wrongly. Should be Tilde

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, just run this command once:

```
scoreboard objectives add test dummy "test"
```

Then have a repeating command block with this command:

```
execute as @a at @s if score @s test = @s 3.. run [enter command here]
```

You can change the `3..` to whatever number you want to test for, for example `5..`

You can add, set, and reset the points with these commands:

```
scoreboard players add [player] test [amount]
scoreboard players set [player] test [amount]
scoreboard players reset [player] test
```

And for all the above commands, you can change the word `test` to whichever objective name you'd like to use.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, and thanks for the answer! It looks like you tried to give a scoreboard setup, but there is a problem with the second command: it's throwing an error. The error message reads as follows: `Unknown scoreboard objective '3..'`. Would you mind fixing your commands here?